# TinyMCE loaded into vue js app for only one time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tinymce, vue-router

I am working on **vue Js** Project and I am using **TinyMCE** Like code below

**Html**

```
<textarea class="tinymcefoo" id="editor">  </textarea> </div>
```

**In Vue js**:  I am calling TinyMCE  into **mounted Life cycle** :

> `mounted()
>          {
>             tinymce.init({ selector:'.tinymcefoo' })
>          }`

**But problem Is it's works for only one time Or If the page fully refreshed. If I click on the menu (using vue router ) it's not working** .

Comment: Anyone please help

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code.  Can you make a fiddle for it?

Comment: I made a video for you to understand what's happening 
 See : https://streamable.com/4ghh2

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the [official documentation](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue), and — also — place `tinymce` in the `data()` object:

```
data() {
  return {
    tinyMCE: {
      init: {
        api: 'API_KEY',
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
          'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',
          'autoresize'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat',
      },
      modelForField: ''
    }
  }
},
```